# Timeout-Dialog.js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, timeout-dialog.js

I am implementing [Timeout-Dialog.js](http://rigoneri.github.io/timeout-dialog.js/) in **ASP.NET MVC 5** project.

So at my layout page I have got

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(function () {
            Timer();
        });

        function Timer() {
            console.log("Set Timeout");
            setTimeout(TimeOut, 10000);
        }

        function TimeOut() {
            $.timeoutDialog({
                timeout: 1,
                countdown: 60,
                keep_alive_url: '@Url.Action("KeepAliveSession", "Account")',
                logout_redirect_url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
                logout_url: '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")',
                restart_on_yes: true
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And I include all files into `BundleConfig`.

```
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",                       
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js ",        
                      "~/Scripts/timeout-dialog/js/timeout-dialog.js"
                      ));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                   "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                   "~/Content/site.css",
                   "~/Content/main.css",
                   "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css",                
                   "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                   "~/Content/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css",
                   "~/Scripts/timeout-dialog/css/timeout-dialog.css"

               ));
```

The dialog appears in time but when I press any of button I am facing this error.

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'close'

[image]
Any clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer: 
[documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773204/timeout-dialog-js-issue)

The issue is with the plugin **Timeout-Dialog.js**

Replace `$(this).dialog('close')` with `$('#timeout-dialog').dialog('close');` in the plugin